# Installing Passenger with NGINX as non-root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am setting up a server where I am not going to use root to install RVM,RoR, NGINX, etc.
So I logon with my user ID and run:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled
```

RVM, Ruby and Rails all get installed nicely.

```
rvm -v
ruby -v
rails -v
```

all return the latest version numbers, just as planned

Now to installing Passenger with NGINX

```
gem install passenger
```

Then preparing the /opt/nginx folder

```
sudo mkdir /opt/nginx
sudo chmod 777 /opt/nginx
```

as it was complaining it cant create the folder (as I am not root)
Now coming to:

```
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

It stops with:

```
Compiling Passenger support files...
# /home/myapp/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rake nginx:clean nginx RELEASE=yes
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- rubygems/builder
```

Whats next?

Comment: did the installation again but this time with Ruby 1.9.3 and it works.  Something broken in 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Ruby 2.0. Ruby 2.0 is supported since Phusion Passenger 4. Phusion Passenger 3 doesn't support it. Phusion Passenger 4 is going to be released next week, but for now you can grab Release Candidate 6 with `gem install passenger --pre`.